# how to select a query with % in below condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am not able to return values for below query. The aim of this is I need to return the values depending on id.
oid are in form `123, 123.456, 123.456.789` . So if the result of `SELECT id FROM table1 where name = 'Test999'`is `456`. it should return 2 columns i.e., `123.456, 123.456.789` . I am trying to give a `%` symbol before the query seems like some syntax error. Tried giving double quotes still no progress.

```
SELECT * from table1 where oid like 
%(SELECT id FROM table1 where name = 'Test999')
```

Comment: Please add data for a sample table, and then also include the output you expect from that input.

Answer (score 0):

I could manage it by adding a percent symbol to the output column of the subquery

```
select *  
  from (select 'aa' q union all select 'bb') some_table
 where some_table.q like (select '%a')
```

Thus, your query must look something like that

```
SELECT * from table1 where oid like 
(SELECT '%'||id FROM table1 where name = 'Test999')
```

What you must be aware of is query will fail whenever subquery returns more than 1 row

UPD: I'm dumb. You just need to eliminate the subquery:

```
SELECT * 
  from table1 t1
  join table1 t2
    on t1.oid like concat('%', t2.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table1 tt1
              WHERE t1.oid LIKE CONCAT('%', tt1.id, '%') AND 
                    tt1.name = 'Test999'
             );
```